# Prevent Prettier from wrapping text content and open/close tags

Tags: html, prettier

I have the following HTML.

```html
    <text x='90' y='170'>1</text>
    <text x='190' y='170'>2</text>
    <text x='290' y='170'>3</text>
```

Which is wrapped by Prettier:

```html
          <text x='90' y='170'>
            1
          </text>
          <text x='190' y='170'>
            2
          </text>
          <text x='290' y='170'>
            3
          </text>
```

See, three lines of HTML is formatted to nine lines.

What can I do to prevent Prettier from wrapping one line of open tag, text content, close tag to three lines?

Answer (score 1):

Set `printWidth` in your **.prettierrc** file:

```json
{
    "printWidth": 80, // set the number higher if you don't want to wrap too many lines
}
```

> Note: If you dont' have **.prettierrc** file, just create one.

Comment: I don't think the following code has more than 80 characters:  ```    <text x='290' y='170'>3</text>```

Comment: 80 is my settings, you can set yours.